# Context help for Java API & language in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Is it possible to set up context help for Java API & language in NetBeans.

For example something like pressing F1 on `ServletContextListener` (for API) or on word `while` (for language) in source code and obtain help on these words.
(something like in Visual Studio for instance)

I am using NetBeans 6.5.

Answer (score 3):

Pressing Alt-F1 will bring up the javadoc in your default browser but you have to have the javadocs installed for the APIs that you're using.

To install the Java SE javadoc for example, go to [java.sun.com](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp) and download the documentation then in Netbeans go to **Tools** > **Java Platform** then click on the **Javadoc** tab. Next, click **Add ZIP/Folder** and select the file you just downloaded.

**Window** > **Other** > **Javadoc** will show a panel with some basic info about the class/interface you highlight.

Comment: Upvoting, but now it became: Window->IDE Tools->Java docs. Shows up  after a click on any  object.

Answer (score 2):

The closest that you can get is ctrl-space to bring up the help (while ctrl-space for example).

Are you looking for something like what Visual Studio does?